# Rails returns error for DELETE view > No route matches [GET] "/assets"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click on the 'delete' link (to delete the project), I wish to show a new page for the user to confirm the deletion ('are you sure' page). But when I click on the link, error **No route matches [GET] "/assets"** appears, I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

This is my projects/index.html.erb

```
  1   <% @projects.each do |p| %>
  2       <%= link_to p.name, project_path(p) %>
  3       <%= link_to "edit", edit_project_path(p) %> 
  4       <%= link_to "delete",{ :action => 'delete', :controller => 'projects', :id => p.id } %> 
  5   <% end %>
```

This is my controllers/projects_controller.rb

```
 38   def delete     
 39     @project = Project.find(params[:id])
 40     render 'delete'
 41   end
 42     
 43   def destroy
 44     project = Project.find(params[:id])
 45     project.destroy
 46     flash[:notice] = "Page succesfully removed"
 47     redirect_to(projects_path)
 48   end
```

This is my views/projects/delete.html.erb

```
  1 <%= form_for(:project, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @project.id }) do |f| %> 
  2   <p>Are you sure you want to remove "<%= @project.name %>"</p>
  3   <%= submit_tag ("Yes, I am sure")
  4 <% end %>
```

EDIT:My Url looks like this >>> http://localhost:3000/assets?action=delete&controller=projects&id=1

EDIT2: **the solution is going to routes.rb and adding this line**

```
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Now the delete page appears. **However, when I click the delete button Rails returns an error >> Unknown action The action '6' could not be found for ProjectsController**

Comment: You need to include your delete view in the question.

Comment: I have thank you. You have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: No, I mean you need to post the code of your delete view within your question rather than the title.

Comment: need to take a look at your routes.rb

Comment: I went in there and uncommented this line >> match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' Now the 'are you sure' page shows, but, when I click submit_tag("Yes,I am sure"), it returns >> Unknown action

The action '6' could not be found for ProjectsController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
<%= form_for(:project, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @project.id }) do |f| %>
```

You're not telling it to use the HTTP method DELETE when making this

```
<%= form_for(:project, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @project.id }, :method => :delete) do |f| %>
```

You could also write this much, much shorter like this:

```
<%= form_for(@project, :method => :delete) do |f| %>
```

Rails will know precisely what URL to build, so you don't need to tell it what to do.

---

**Bonus**

You could also do this with the initial `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "delete", [:delete, project], :method => :delete %>
```

The array as the second argument here will compile the route using the polymorphic route builder in Rails.